# If graphql is a query language, why is it used on frontend and not on backend?

Tags: api, graphql

I've always been taught that performing queries on the frontend it is considered a bad practice and I should create a secure API endpoint instead.

Answer (score 0):

The frontend has to tell the backend what data it wants from the backend. Not really writing queries, just fetching data.